# Exporting in React higher order components

Tags: reactjs

```
function logProps(WrappedComponent) {
  class LogProps extends React.Component {
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      console.log('old props:', prevProps);
      console.log('new props:', this.props);
    }

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  }

  return LogProps;
}


class FancyButton extends React.Component {
  focus() {
    // ...
  }

  // ...
}

// Rather than exporting FancyButton, we export LogProps.
// It will render a FancyButton though.
export default logProps(FancyButton);
```

I have taken these pieces of code from the react documentation, however i am confused about what actually happens during

```
export default logProps(FancyButton);
```

My thoughts are that it probably calls the function logProps which in React is considered a higher order component which in that case it should being with capital letter to avoid ambiguity.
The logProp function defines a class component LogProps, the class component LogProps renders an argument component FancyButton. The class component LogProps is then returned from the function.

```
import FancyButton from './FancyButton';

const ref = React.createRef();

// The FancyButton component we imported is the LogProps HOC.
// Even though the rendered output will be the same,
// Our ref will point to LogProps instead of the inner FancyButton component!
// This means we can't call e.g. ref.current.focus()
<FancyButton
  label="Click Me"
  handleClick={handleClick}
  ref={ref}
/>;
```

The returnedcomponent(LogProps, FancyButton) from the function logProps is then imported and instantiated at

```
<FancyButton
  label="Click Me"
  handleClick={handleClick}
  ref={ref}
/>
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this correct?

Almost.

As stated in docs, [Higher Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html):

> is a **function** that takes a component and returns a new component.

- `HOC`s name don't start with capital letter.
- There's no need to name the returned component.

To simplify, the HOC function basically just returns a new and enhanced component. That's it.

This will also work:

```
// camel case
function logProps(WrappedComponent) {
  // no name
  return class extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} {...this.someEnhancements} />;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah right so there is a difference between React class/function components and higher order components, thank you

Comment: @YaGetMeh glad to be of help!